# Dynamic HTTP Header in react Native

Tags: api, react-native, dynamic, http-headers, react-native-ios

I am developing an app with react native. In the app, we are using bearer token for security reasons to call the API. I have managed to call the API with static header content. However, I am struggling to find a way to update the header "Authorization" dynamically. I have created a Utility class and get the header values from there. But I do not understand how to set the Authorization key dynamically. I have created below method:

```
Utility.headers = function() {
  return {
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "accept": "application/json",
  "api-token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

This method will return API headers. But my Authorization value is dynamic. And I do not know how to make it dynamic. Please help me with this. I am new to react native

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your authorization header using the AsyncStorage.

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('bearer', '...');
```

Then get inside your function.

Like so:

```
    Utility.headers = async function () {
    const jwt = await AsyncStorage.getItem('bearer');

    return {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "api-token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + jwt
    }
}
```

You can read more about the AsyncStorage here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: Thanks @animaonline, I am getting JWT token using API. Shall I use AsyncStorage with API response?

Comment: @user3894856 you're welcome,don't forget to mark my answer as the correct answer if it actually works for you.